# If address is changed in account it should replicate in all related contact's address

Tags: salesforce

How to do it using triggers in **salesforce** and **bulkify** it.

Comment: Did you try to implement it somehow already? It looks like usual case for Apex triggers or SF workflows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, here is one method that you can call from your Account trigger:

```
public static void afterUpdate(List<Account> newList, List<Account> oldList){
  Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
  for ( Integer i=0;i<newList.size();i++ ){
    if ( newList[i].BillingStreet != oldList[i].BillingStreet ){
      accountIds.add(newList[i].Id);
    }
  }
  List<Contact> contactsToUpdate = new List<Contact>();
  for ( Contact c : [
    SELECT Id, MailingStreet, Account.BillingStreet
    FROM Contact
    WHERE AccountId IN :accountIds
  ]){
    if ( c.MailingStreet != c.Account.BillingStreet ){
      c.MailingStreet = c.Account.BillingStreet;
      contactsToUpdate.add(c);
    }
  }
  if ( contactsToUpdate.size() > 0 ){
    update contactsToUpdate;
  }
}
```